# Unicity of the limit for weak convergence in different spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f_n\in L^4(\mathbb{R})\cap L^3(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose that
$$ f_n\rightarrow f \mbox{  weak in } L^3$$
$$ f_n\rightarrow \tilde{f} \mbox{  weak in } L^4$$
***Can i conclude that $f=\tilde{f}$ almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$?***

This is not clear, because weak convergence doesn't imply convergence a.e along a subsequence. I'm interested also in the case where both convergence are weak*, and in the case where one convergence is weak and the other is weak*.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: It follows that $$\int\phi f=\int\phi\tilde f$$for  every $\phi\in L^{4/3}\cap L^{3/2}$.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. And what about weak* convergence? the same trick doesn't work right?

Comment: @Capublanca I don't see why weak* convergence is any different.

Comment: OK, for sure it's the same in the case $L^4$ and $L^3$. But what if we have $L^1$ (or $L^{\infty})$?

Comment: @Capublanca There's no such thing as weak* convergence in $L^1$, since $L^1$ is not a dual space. What if we have weak convergence in $L^1$ and weak* convergence in $L^\infty$? That's no different - we still have $\int \phi f=\int\phi \tilde f$ for every $\phi\in L^1\cap L^\infty$...

Comment: @Capublanca One might be concerned about the case where we have weak convergence in $L^\infty$, since we don't have a good handle on the dual of $L^\infty$. But that doesn't matter either; it's still true that $L^1\subset (L^\infty)^*$.

Comment: I'm convinced, thank you very much!